# Codeigniter form elements as table

Tags: html, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a form in Codeigniter so that its elements are part of a table and are therefore aligned nicely. Here's the view page:

```
<div id="login">
<h3>Log in</h3>

<?php

$attributes = array('id'=>'form_login');

echo validation_errors();

echo form_open('login/main', $attributes);

//probably a bad idea to load libraries in views, but what the heck?!
$this->load->library('table');
$this->table->add_row('Username', form_input('username'));
echo $this->table->generate();
//echo 'Username: ';
//echo form_input('username') . '</br>';

echo 'Password: ';
echo form_password('password') . '</br>';

echo form_submit('submit', 'Log in');
?>

<br/><br/>

<a href="#">Forgot Password</a> <br/>
<a href="#">New User? Register</a>
</div>
```

The two lines commented out is how it was earlier. Now I'm getting the following error: **Call to a member function add_row() on a non-object**. Why is **table** a non-object? I've tried loading the library in the controller but the error persists. Please help!

Comment: Have you thought about using CSS to align your elements instead of a table? It might save you a lot of headache.

Comment: @dotslash, when your controller extends from CI_Controller or your model Extends from CI_Molde you can use $this. in view you need to get instance from CI to have it

Comment: @Zarazthuztra Thanks, but CSS is itself a lot of headache when aligning form elements. Consider a situation where I have multiple labels and textboxes. to use CSS, I'll have to assign all of them a class or id and then define a number of rules. When it comes to forms, I think tables are more natural.

Comment: @MajidGolshadi Good point! Thanks for the comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In codeigniter, the global codeigniter object is not available in your views, so you have to get a reference to it.

Try the following

```
$ci =& get_instance();
```

Put that at the top, and replace your calls to $this like so:

```
$ci->load->library('table');
$ci->table->add_row('Username', form_input('username'));
echo $ci->table->generate();
```

Comment: This is the coolest answer ever! Thanks so much. The &= was throwing an error saying "Undefined variable ci" but then I changed it to = and it worked. Any idea why that might happen (I'm new to PHP)? Thanks again and happy new year! :) :)

Comment: Syntax error on my part actually, should have bee =& which is setting $ci to a reference of what is returned by get_instance()
Happy new year!

Comment: Cool, thanks! :) One final question: How does it matter if I return a reference or create a new variable? Other than memory consumption, I mean.

Comment: Sometimes I think I know everything about CI. And then other times I get a question like that that makes me go...let me go look that up somewhere, because I honestly have no idea what happens. That's just how I learned to go about it over time.

Comment: LOL. Thanks for the honest answer. See you around!